# Use Windows Azure Service Bus Queues in Android

Tags: java, android, azure, sdk, servicebus

Is there an alternative to accessing Windows Azure Service Bus queues from an android application that doesn't involve working directly with HTTP requests? For instance, a third-party library or SDK, or instructions on how to use the Windows Azure SDK for Java on Android projects?

The [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java) apparently is not compatibile with Android. My understanding is that it directly references some core libraries such as javax.inject. Trying to use it on an Android project via Maven resulted in errors such as `trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class"` and `Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.`

The [wa-toolkit-android](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-android/tree/master/library/storage/src/com/windowsazure/samples/android/storageclient) only supports Storage, not Service Bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Windows Azure SDK for Java](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) it includes library and sample code on how to use Service Bus queues and topics. [Here's also a post on how to use Queues from plain java](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/), in case it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I think that at this time to use Service Bus queues from Android the best way is to implement it based on the sources you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Windows Azure Mobile Services which supports Service Bus from Node.js. This is explained by Scott Guthrie here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/10/16/windows-azure-mobile-services-new-support-for-ios-apps-facebook-twitter-google-identity-emails-sms-blobs-service-bus-and-more.aspx. Node.js and service bus explanation is here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/

Today, Android can connect to Windows Azure Mobile services as explained by Chris Risner here: http://chrisrisner.com/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services-and-Android

Comment: Thank you. That's a helpful answer, even though I'm looking for native Java classes that would access Service Bus directly instead of through a proxy service I'd have to pay additionally for. But Mobile Services is definitely an option worth considering when developing for mobile devices and I'll look further into it.

Comment: Note that if you have low traffic, Windows Azure Mobile services is free. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-0